# KL-divergence returns infinity

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Given an original probability distribution *P*, I want to measure how much an approximation *Q* differs from the initial distribution. For that I calculate the KL-divergence via `scipy.stats.entropy`, which returns infinity due to the large difference. However, as with time the approximation becomes better, I still want to quantify the divergence between the two sets.

The question is, is there any hack to avoid `inf` values or should I circumvent the behaviour by using some other distance measure?

Comment: I had the same problem and I saw that my x-axes weren't aligned so some adjustments were required as a "hack" when these happened. Read here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743201/interpreting-scipy-stats-entropy-values

Answer (score 7):

The infinity is due to divide by zero. 
Just replace any zero value with a very small value.
This question is very common , if you search for it you will find many questions similar to it . 
Remember that kl is not a metric

Comment: Even though I replaced all items in the array by 0.00001, it still returns infinity after the computation... However, I feed the function an unnormalized version so it can transform it into a normalized one. Might this be the problem?

Comment: This should be by default. Kl works on distributions. You need to convert to probability, replace any zero value with a very small value

Comment: My output changes significantly based on whether I change 0's to 10E-20 or to 10E-300.  Any idea on why such a large change?